# Why won't scrollspy work in Bootstrap 4 if i use ./ in the href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, scrollspy

If I remove `./` from the `href` attribute then it works fine. Why?

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md" id="navbar1">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#top">
      <img src="./img/logo.png" alt="" class="img-fluid logo">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link" href="./#features">Features <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="./#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="./#services">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="./#video-play">Showreel</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="./#gallery">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="./#team">Team</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href=./ "#news">News</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="./#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shop</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item apply-now text-white">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="./form-fee-easy.html">Apply Now</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```js
$('body').scrollspy({
  target: '#navbar1'
});
```

Comment: From the docs: `Anchors (<a>) are required and must point to an element with that id.` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/#how-it-works

Comment: Here's an example of a body section that doesn't highlight when I scroll down to it:

    <section id="features" >
              content
     </section>

Comment: is there a way so that i can trim ./ from href attribute

Comment: If the `#features` element is in the same page, which it needs to be for scrollspy to work, why do you need the `./` in the URL in the first place?

Comment: i needed ./ because when from another page i click features in the navbar it won't work without it

Comment: So how can the scrollspy work at all if the elements you're targettng in the scroll are on another page? That makes no sense.